# Horror sea creature film

Tags: story-identification, movie

In the '70s at a drive-in theater with my parents I saw a film. It involved a sea creature. The movie starts with the creature killing a girl on a boat. It's like in a harbor with fishing boats. Two men with a fishing boat set out to kill it. I remember it having an exposed brain that glowed blue. No, it's not *[Humanoids From the Deep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanoids_from_the_Deep)*.

Can anyone help name the movie?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! I see this is your second question but just so you know there is [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) which details how you can include the relevant information for a positive id. If you haven't done so already be sure to take the [tour]!

Comment: I mean, besides the glowing brain part, this sounds almost exactly like [Jaws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaws_(film))

Comment: Did the sea creatures have a strange attraction to electrical devices?

Comment: Besides the glowing brain, what did the monster look like? Sharky? Squiddish? Crablike?

Comment: creature was humanoid is shape. like humanoids from the deep.

Comment: i thought they killed it by electrocuting it on their boat.

Comment: a "strange attraction to electricity" seems right.

Comment: i'd have to say more "creature from the black lagoon" looking.

Comment: sorry to the person who posted the list of movies, deleting your list was not helpful by the admins. it turns out the slithis is one of the movies i saw at the drive-in. however, i dont think it was the only one or the specific one i am looking for. i do appreciate the help remembering slithis though.

Comment: can we give partial credit to the guy with the first answer for slithis?

Comment: @Möoz More like *Ghost Shark* or whatever it was called. It had like a shark that was killed and came back as a ghost and yada yada yada.

Comment: definitely not ghost shark.

Comment: Was there a scene where the creature comes out of the water, and starts to 'shed' its water layer and then sort of immediately adapts to breathing out of the water?

Comment: @RogerLawhorn - possibly not helpful, I apologize, but dumping a list of possibilities isn't how answers are typically handled here.  If Liam doesn't know but has more possibilities to discuss with you, you guys can use either comments or chat.  If we (the people that voted) were wrong in deleting the list, one of the mods will let us know and reverse it.  Again, apologies.

Comment: no adapting to breathing. i thought you had it with the attraction to electricity Mooz. apparently we saw a lot of horror flicks and somehow they are being blurred together as one memory. however, the memory i posted is very specific and has very specific scenes not found in slithis so still searching.

Comment: @Roger Lawhorn Do you know (or could you make a guess) about the country of origin of the film? US? UK? And, was the film a new release when you saw it (or do you know if it was released in the 1970's, or older and being replayed)? Any other scenes iconic or stand out for you..?

Comment: definitely usa in english. i think the film was new, definitely not older. slithis was 1978 so probably from the same time plus or minus a few years. involved a fishing area like a canal like slithis. all i really remember is the ending. thanks for trying

Comment: bounty ends in 3 days. i want to thanks all those that tried. i have remembered slithis and night of the lepus so far.

Comment: how do i award the bounty to someone?

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm this is the right film as I don't own it and it's been many years since I have seen it, but it could be; Island of the Fishmen!

Comment: This would be a better answer if you include some details from the movie that confirm why you think it's the one the OP is looking for.

Comment: You might want to take the [tour] as this is a question and answer site not a normal discussion forum. Answers should answer the question only and some of your previous answers have been more of a discussion than an actual answer.

Comment: They are blue, but no exposed brains that I can see. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mi1Hu5uczBY

Comment: sorry, its not island of the fishmen. i searched for that film.